# Simple question about Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a following Makefile for tiobench. I wrote it. The problem is, when I do `make all` , this does not leave me in the install directory as it should. Why ?

```
# Makefile for tiotest

#include $(shell while [ "`pwd`" != / -a \! -r options.mk ]; do cd .. ; done ; pwd )/options.mk

#CFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall
CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall

#DEFINES=-DUSE_MMAP 
#-DUSE_MADVISE

# This enables support for 64bit file offsets, allowing
# possibility to test with files larger than (2^31) bytes.

#DEFINES=-DLARGEFILES

#DEFINES=

MODULE=tiotest
PROJECT=tiobench
# do it once instead of each time referenced
VERSION=$(shell egrep "tiotest v[0-9]+.[0-9]+" tiotest.c | cut -d " " -f 7 | sed "s/v//g")
DISTNAME=$(PROJECT)-$(VERSION)

INSTALL := $(CURDIR)/install
INSTALL_DIR := $(INSTALL)/test/bin
BOM := $(CURDIR)/BOM
BUILDRESULTS := $(CURDIR)/buildresults
MODULE := tiotest

build: $(MODULE)

crc32.o: crc32.c crc32.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) crc32.c -o crc32.o

tiotest.o: tiotest.c tiotest.h crc32.h crc32.c Makefile
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) tiotest.c -o tiotest.o

$(MODULE): tiotest.o crc32.o
    $(CC) -o $(MODULE) tiotest.o crc32.o -lpthread
    @echo
    @echo "./tiobench.pl --help for usage options"
    @echo

configure:

clean: clean-install
    rm -f tiotest.o crc32.o $(MODULE) core

distclean: clean

clean-install:
    -rm -rf $(INSTALL) $(BUILDRESULTS)

install: clean-install build
    mkdir -p $(INSTALL_DIR)
    cp $(MODULE) $(INSTALL_DIR)
    #$(STRIP) $(INSTALL_DIR)/$(MODULE)
    @echo install tree is in $(INSTALL)

buildresults: install
    mkdir $(BUILDRESULTS)
    cd install && tar cf - `cat $(BOM)` | (cd $(BUILDRESULTS) ; tar xfp -)
    @echo buildresults tree is in $(BUILDRESULTS)

all: distclean configure build install buildresults

.PHONY: build clean-install install buildresults clean distclean all
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not leave me in the install directory"?

Comment: I meant I should be left in ./install after `make all` which does not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the commands are run in a sub shell. they can't effect the current working directory of the shell from which you ran `make all`

Comment: `cd install` in `cd install && tar cf - \`cat $(BOM)\` | (cd $(BUILDRESULTS) ; tar xfp -)` is not run in a sub shell. If I run `cd install && tar cf - \`cat $(BOM)\` | (cd $(BUILDRESULTS) ; tar xfp -)` on command line with proper directories in place, I am left in ./install.

Comment: yes, that's correct when you run it in the current shell but `make` runs its shell commands in a new sub shell